# Need to cap a ceiling fan pull-chain switch hole

Tags: ceiling-fan, fans

I recently installed ceiling fans along with a remote-control module to adjust speed. As a result, I do not need or want the pull-chains to control the speed of the fan or turn on/off the light. Removing the switch itself is a trivial electrical problem of cutting the wires and tying them together, but I'm left with an ugly hole in the side of the fan.

Is there something I can use to nicely cap the hole? The fans are polished brass if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a [hole plug](http://www.stimpson.com/hole-plugs/standard-hole-plugs/) something like this

[image: hole plug]

These are similar to electrical knockout plugs.

If you can't find a source, you could use a [brass cap](http://www.homedepot.com/s/brass%2520caps?NCNI-5) on the outside and a short machine screw on the inside (with a washer if needed).

[image: brass cap]

In either case, you need to be certain the capping material is not interfering with existing mechanisms or wires. Since the pull chain switch was previously in that location, room should not be a problem.

<sub>Images and links are for reference only and are not an endorsement of any product or company.</sub>

Comment: I was looking for a "hole plug" but didn't know the term. Now that I do, Google is very helpful. Thanks!